# How to rename a variable in Eclipse JEE Mars 2?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to rename a variable and all its references in my code base. I am using **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Mars.2 Release (4.5.2))**.

When I right-click, I do not see any menu item called Rename in any of the context-menus or sub-menus.

I looked up all the context menu items before posting this question. The first place I looked was the **Refactor \ Rename** context-menu item because that's where I would have found it in Visual Studio. I am a C# developer.

Comment: alt-shift-r should help you out

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for the keyboard shortcut. That is very useful. Which menu item will I find this command in? Just curious.

Comment: May I ask ahy are you using a really outdated version of Eclipse?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Java editor because all the answers saying 'Refactor > Rename' are correct? Right click on the Java file and select 'Open With...' and check 'Java editor' is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I right-click, I do not see any menu item called Rename

The menu item is `Refactor`, under which you have `Rename`.

Comment: No, it doesn't have that. I looked up all of it before posting the question.

Comment: Then it means you are not right-clicking on an occurrence of a variable (or method, or class, or anything that can be renamed). Usually right-click menus (or "context menus") have a content that depends on where the cursor is when you right-click.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 I stand corrected, it means the cursor was not on a variable. As you pointed out in a comment, just right-clicking somewhere does not move the cursor there before showing the context menu. So the context menu you get does not depend on where you right-click but on where the cursor is when you right-click. Which is kind of weird, I agree. Also because the location where the menu appears is where you right-clicked but the menu items don't refer to that.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the context menu `Refactor \ Rename...`.

And the keyboard shortcut is `Alt+Shift+R`.

You first have to select the variable you want to rename and then use either the context menu (right click) on it, or use the shortcut.

Comment: Nope, it isn't there. That was where I looked *first* because that is where I would find it in Visual Studio. I am a C# developer. I looked around all the context-menu items before posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Select the variable pres Alt + Shift + R and type new name.
Or Select the variable -> right click -> Refactor -> Rename and type new name

Comment: Ok, I got what I was doing wrong. I had not *selected* the variable name before right-clicking. I had only had my mouse cursor on the variable name before I right-clicked. In Visual Studio, you can just have  your mouse cursor on the variable and right-click and the **Refactor \ Rename** shows up. Apparently, this doesn't happen with Eclipse unless you select the whole variable name. Thank you for the help. :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 You don't need to select the whole variable name. You just need the cursor (not the mouse pointer) to be on the variable name.

Comment: Damn it. This is strange. Up until now, I tried that many times but it wouldn't show me the **Rename** command at all if I just had the cursor on the variable name. Now it does. I swear to God.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 It's possible that since you tried many times, not each single time you went through all the submenus of all the menu items - that would take quite a while to do many times. Maybe the times when you had the cursor on the variable you just looked at the first-level menu items.